# JavaScript - if value exist in array return object key

Tags: javascript

I got an object of three array ranges (*high, medium, low*) containing **random** numbers.
How can i search through all three value arrays and return the object key for the one that matches the search number?

**Example:**

```
const search = "63";

const rangesObj = {
  high: [67, 94, 57],
  medium: [43, 89, 63, 12],
  low: [27, 41, 77, 99],
};

// returns *undefined*, should return *medium*
console.log(Object.keys(rangesObj).find(val => search.includes(val)))
```

Comment: `Object.entries(rangesObj).find(([key, numbers])=>numbers.includes(+search))`

Comment: Given that they are random numbers, could the number exist in more than one array, and if so, what should be returned?

Comment: Good question! The first value, how should this be solved?

Comment: @Fjott Well, the current answer seems fine to me for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use `rangesObj[key]` to get the array corresponding to each particular key, then use `Array#includes`.
- `search` needs to be converted to a number first so that the types match.

```js
const search = "63";
const rangesObj = {
  high: [67, 94, 57],
  medium: [43, 89, 63, 12],
  low: [27, 41, 77, 99],
};
console.log(Object.keys(rangesObj).find(k => rangesObj[k].includes(+search)));
```

Answer (score 1):

`val` in your example is the key, so you'll need `rangeObj[key]` to let `include()` do his thing.

Also, convert `search` to number (`+search`) otherwise it wont match

```js
const search = "63";

const rangesObj = {
  high: [67, 94, 57],
  medium: [43, 89, 63, 12],
  low: [27, 41, 77, 99],
};


const res = Object.keys(rangesObj).find(key => rangesObj[key].includes(+search))
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
Object.keys(rangesObj).find(x => rangesObj[x].includes(+search))
```